# How to add tilt control to google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So I disabled the UI of google map embed into my website using `disableDefaultUI: true`but now I want to add the tilt option on map which allows us to see different views of the map.

EDIT: Question was already answered. `rotateControl: true`

Comment: Have you checked the official API documentation to see if you can control the tilt programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the "tilt" control, you can only display that in conjunction with the rotate control.  To enable that, add `rotateControl: true` to your mapOptions:

```
rotateControl: true
```

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v322-controls-diff):

> **New (v3.22 default):**
>
> Appearance: The Rotate control appears as **two visible controls** that perform different functions. The first is a tilt button, allowing the user to tilt the imagery to a 45° angle. The second is a rotate button, allowing the user to change the bearing of the imagery when tilted.
>   Default position: RIGHT_BOTTOM.

**Note** (as @Matthew pointed out in the comments) you will only see the rotate controls in areas with 45 degree imagery (city centres etc)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 45.518,
      lng: -122.672
    },
    zoom: 18,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    tilt: 45,
    rotateControl: true
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```